# Conditionally sum specific columns in multiple column table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets, sum, conditional-statements

I have a timetable that shows every day of the year. The columns are headed   with month names and `h` (for hour). If I mark a day with a label I put a number on the `h` column right next to it. These numbers should be summed up whenever the appropriate label is found.

[Example of my timetable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLGu3.png) 
[image]

So the formula (not query!) should look for a specific label on the whole timetable and sum all numbers right next to it in one cell.

I've tried several solutions but I guess I just don't understand the mechanism of array formulae to achieve a solution and even the SUMIFS function doesn't get me anywhere.

Comment: Is good enough. But I guess that Excel functions are quite similiar to GoogleSpreadsheets functions. The more generic the better. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=SUMIF(B4:Y34,"WM",C4:Z34)
```

works for me. Don't know why `sumifs` didn't for you but then you haven't said what your problem was with it.

Comment: Well... it must have been a deadlock of my brain. I tried that several times except that the range of the 3rd argument was always exactly the same as the first, which lead to nowhere. Why is that?
Besides: THANK YOU VERY MUCH!

Comment: I've tried a lot of formulas and i gave it up by deleting it. Yeah that seems logical. Classical no brainer. Thank you!